# Logic Pro - 1/2X label on loops?

Tags: logic-pro

I've noticed that when I add an audio loop to a Logic Pro project, it sometimes (depending on the project tempo) has a `1/2X` label added to it which reduces the tempo by one half. Here's an example - if I add the loop to the project with the tempo set to 102, there's no label, and it re-tempos the loop to 102 BPM.

[image: 102 BPM]

If I set the project tempo to 170 BPM, it now has the `1/2X` label and the tempo is reduced:

[image: 170 BPM]

My questions are:

1. How can I disable this or get rid of it if I don't want it to happen?
2. How do I *force* it if I do want it to happen?

Comment: I'm gonna guess this is some semi-smart structure attempting to protect you from yourself. Someone has determined a maximum possible speed they can re-interpret that sample at & any attempt to exceed it will automatically half-pace it. [I don't use Logic (or this type of smart loop) much so I can't answer your actual question]

Comment: Nope, I'm experiencing the same problem, but it was fine before. Try dragging the loop into another track lane. That worked for me. Still don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

### Clarification

First of all, the track content shown in the screenshot (Rock Bass 04) is NOT a regular audio loop. It's an [Apple Loop](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/logicpro/lgcp734a05f6/mac).

How do you you differentiate just by looking at it?
[image]

If you notice, track has a small sign right after track name. That tells the user if it is an Apple Loops[image], regular stereo audio[image] or regular mono audio[image].

### Apple Loops

These are prerecorded musical phrases or riffs in the Loop Browser which when added to a project creates a region and `plays at the project tempo and key`

So even if your project is at say 90 BPM/C Maj and the Apple Loop is at 80 BPM/D Maj, it will stretch it automatically to 90 BPM and transpose it to D Maj when you add it to your project.

### What about the [image] label

If the project BPM is closer to double the Apple Loop BPM, it will avoid stretching the loop and would show a 1/2X label which means it is playing at half the intended speed.

If the project BPM is closer to half the Apple Loop BPM, it will avoid squeezing the loop and would show a 2X label [image] which means it is playing at double the intended speed.

In this specific case, the Apple Loop in question - Rock Bass 04 - has a default BPM of 80
[image]

So, when project BPM is 102, the loop gets stretched as it is closer to 80 but when project BPM is 170, it being closer to 160 (2 times 80) it internally stretches to 85 (1/2 times 170) and marks a `1/2x` label in the track name to indicate it.

If you try playing the loop in 40, you'll see a `2x` label.

The intuitive reasoning behind this is to keep the audio as close to the original as possible and to avoid over-stretching the audio hence reducing artefacts.

### How to force follow the project BPM (and remove the label)

There are 2 ways -

1. Make the project BPM same as the Apple Loop BPM, import the Apple Loop and then change the project BPM
   [image]
2. Bounce the Apple Loop as a regular audio loop and then use Time and Pitch Machine (^P) to change the BPM.

[image]

---

Reference Logic Pro ver : 10.7.2